# Understanding has_friendship gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am a Ruby on Rails developer and wanted to learn more about Ruby as a language. My first approach was to study open source gems and so, started with `has_frienship` gem.

Although, I know SOME of things that are there but confused about alot.

The gem asks to put `has_friendship` word inside the model against which migrations will be copied from the gem and tables will be made using polymorphic associations.

- When I put the word `has_friendship in any model`, then, `which line of code` in the gem checks it's presence or absence.

I am unable to find that and will really appreciate your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

when you put `has_friendship` in any model

then it will just load all the `has_friendship.rb` code into the model

check this for more [better ruby idioms by yehudakatz](https://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/) and [Add an "acts_as" Method to Active Record](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#add-an-acts-as-method-to-active-record)